# Attribute error in defining spatial networks in Lasagne

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, lasagne

I couldn't find much examples of using spatial networks in lasagne so it is possible that I might be making a mistake in defining my network. Please look at my network definition and let me know if the fault lies with my network configuration or there's some other issue.

```
net = NeuralNet(

```
layers=[('loc_input',    InputLayer),
        ('loc_conv2d1',  Conv2DLayer),
        ('loc_maxpool1', MaxPool2DLayer),
        ('loc_conv2d2',  Conv2DLayer),
        ('loc_maxpool2', MaxPool2DLayer),
        ('loc_dense',    DenseLayer),
        ('loc_output',   DenseLayer),

        ('STN1', TransformerLayer),

        ('conv2d1',  Conv2DLayer),
        ('maxpool1', MaxPool2DLayer),
        ('conv2d2',  Conv2DLayer),
        ('maxpool2', MaxPool2DLayer),
        ('dense',    DenseLayer),
        ('dropout1', DropoutLayer),
        ('dense',    DenseLayer),
        ('output',   DenseLayer),
        ],

loc_input_shape=(None, 1, X_train.shape[2],X_train.shape[3]),
# layer conv2d1
loc_conv2d1_num_filters=32,
loc_conv2d1_filter_size=(5, 5),
loc_conv2d1_stride=2,
loc_conv2d1_W=lasagne.init.HeUniform(),  
# layer maxpool1
loc_maxpool1_pool_size=(2, 2),    
# layer conv2d2
loc_conv2d2_num_filters=64,
loc_conv2d2_filter_size=(5, 5),
loc_conv2d2_stride=2,
loc_conv2d2_W=lasagne.init.HeUniform(),
# layer maxpool2
loc_maxpool2_pool_size=(2, 2),
loc_dense_num_units=64,     
# dense
loc_output_num_units=6, 

#Spatial Transformer Network
STN1_incoming = 'loc_input',
STN1_localization_network = 'loc_output',
STN1_downsample_factor = 1,

# layer conv2d1
conv2d1_incoming = 'STN1',
conv2d1_num_filters=32,
conv2d1_filter_size=(3, 3),
conv2d1_stride=2,
conv2d1_nonlinearity=lasagne.nonlinearities.rectify,
conv2d1_W=lasagne.init.GlorotUniform(),  
# layer maxpool1
maxpool1_pool_size=(2, 2),    
# layer conv2d2
conv2d2_num_filters=64,
conv2d2_filter_size=(3, 3),
conv2d2_stride=2,
conv2d2_nonlinearity=lasagne.nonlinearities.rectify,
# layer maxpool2
maxpool2_pool_size=(2, 2),
# dropout1
dropout1_p=0.5,    
# dense
dense_num_units=256,
dense_nonlinearity=lasagne.nonlinearities.rectify,       
# output
output_nonlinearity= softmax,
output_num_units=numClasses,

# optimization method params
update=nesterov_momentum,
update_learning_rate=0.01,
update_momentum=0.9,
max_epochs=20,
verbose=1,
)
```

```

When I initiate the network, I get the following error:

````
```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-84-29eabf8b9697> in <module>()
----> 1 net.initialize()

D:\Python Directory\winPython 2.7\python-2.7.10.amd64\lib\site-packages\nolearn\lasagne\base.pyc in initialize(self)
    360         out = getattr(self, '_output_layer', None)
    361         if out is None:
--> 362             out = self._output_layer = self.initialize_layers()
    363         self._check_for_unused_kwargs()
    364 

D:\Python Directory\winPython 2.7\python-2.7.10.amd64\lib\site-packages\nolearn\lasagne\base.pyc in initialize_layers(self, layers)
    452             try:
    453                 layer_wrapper = layer_kw.pop('layer_wrapper', None)
--> 454                 layer = layer_factory(**layer_kw)
    455             except TypeError as e:
    456                 msg = ("Failed to instantiate {} with args {}.\n"

D:\Python Directory\winPython 2.7\python-2.7.10.amd64\lib\site-packages\lasagne\layers\special.pyc in __init__(self, incoming, localization_network, downsample_factor, **kwargs)
    408                  **kwargs):
    409         super(TransformerLayer, self).__init__(
--> 410             [incoming, localization_network], **kwargs)
    411         self.downsample_factor = as_tuple(downsample_factor, 2)
    412 

D:\Python Directory\winPython 2.7\python-2.7.10.amd64\lib\site-packages\lasagne\layers\base.pyc in __init__(self, incomings, name)
    246         self.input_shapes = [incoming if isinstance(incoming, tuple)
    247                              else incoming.output_shape
--> 248                              for incoming in incomings]
    249         self.input_layers = [None if isinstance(incoming, tuple)
    250                              else incoming

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'output_shape'
````

```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution lies in defining the layers in native lasagne and passing on the final layer to no learn because no learn's Neural Net implementation possibly doesn't recognize the incoming attribute. The following modification for the above network worked for me.

```
l1 = InputLayer  ( shape= (None, 1, X_train.shape[2],X_train.shape[3]))
l2 = Conv2DLayer ( l1, num_filters=32, filter_size=(3, 3), stride=2, W=lasagne.init.HeUniform())
l3 = MaxPool2DLayer ( l2, pool_size=(2, 2) )
l4 = Conv2DLayer ( l3, num_filters=64, filter_size=(3, 3), stride=2, W=lasagne.init.HeUniform())
l5 = MaxPool2DLayer ( l4, pool_size=(2, 2) )
l6 = DenseLayer ( l5, num_units=64 )
l7 = DenseLayer ( l6, num_units=6 )
l8 = TransformerLayer ( l1, l7 , downsample_factor=1.0)
l9 = Conv2DLayer ( l8, num_filters=32, filter_size=(3, 3), stride=2, W=lasagne.init.GlorotUniform(), 
                  nonlinearity=lasagne.nonlinearities.rectify)
l10 = MaxPool2DLayer ( l9, pool_size=(2, 2) )
l11 = Conv2DLayer ( l10, num_filters=64, filter_size=(3, 3), stride=2, W=lasagne.init.GlorotUniform(), 
                  nonlinearity=lasagne.nonlinearities.rectify)
l12 = MaxPool2DLayer ( l11, pool_size=(2, 2) )
l13 = DropoutLayer ( l12,  p =0.5)
l14 = DenseLayer ( l13, num_units=256,  nonlinearity=lasagne.nonlinearities.rectify)
finalLayer = DenseLayer ( l14, num_units=numClasses,  nonlinearity=softmax)


net = NeuralNet(
    finalLayer,
    update=nesterov_momentum,
    update_learning_rate=0.01,
    update_momentum=0.9,
    max_epochs=100,
    verbose=1,
    )
```